# Check if folder exist, if needed create from entry in a table

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I use PowerQuery to create a table from databases and manage files.

There are some files I need to move to a specific folder, depending the value in some column. No need in my VBA code to check those, all the various checks are done with PowerQuery.

My results are in column 3 as in the table below.

| filename | folder\filename | completepath\newfolder |
| --- | --- | --- |
| filename1 | folder1 and filename1 combination | complete path folder1 |
| filename 2 | folder2 and filename2 combination | complete path folder2 |
| filename 3 | folder1 and filename2 combination | complete path folder1 |

My VBA code is just to move the files listed in my generated table.
I need to create the folder, if needed, before moving my files.

The code I tried.

```
Sub Move_Date()
    Dim TAncNouv(), L&

    '**
    Dim Fobj As Object
    Set Fobj = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    '**

    ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path: ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    TAncNouv = ActiveSheet.Range("MovetoFolder[fileName]").Resize(, 3).Value

    '**
    If Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 3)) = False Then
        MkDir (TAncNouv(L, 3))
    End If
    '**

    For L = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
        Name TAncNouv(L, 1) As TAncNouv(L, 2)
    Next L
End Sub
```

(between ** the part I added)

I have an error

> "subscript out of range"

for the line `If Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 3)) = False Then`

I imagine that it doesn't get the value in my third column.

I tried to move my If in the For loop

```vb
Sub Move_Date()
    Dim TAncNouv(), L&
    Dim Fobj As Object
    Set Fobj = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path: ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
    TAncNouv = ActiveSheet.Range("MovetoFolder[fileName]").Resize(, 3).Value
    
    For L = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
        If Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 3)) = False Then
            MkDir (TAncNouv(L, 3))
        End If
        Name TAncNouv(L, 1) As TAncNouv(L, 2)
    Next L
End Sub
```

I have a

> Error 1004 "Application defined or Error defined error"

that I understand even less.

Comment: Arrays from a range's `.Value` will always be one-based. In your first snippet, `L` is equal to `0` so `TAncNouv(L, 3)` throws the subscript out of range.

Comment: oh it's strange, because the code I'm using in various other table (only to rename in same folder ) was ```Sub ReName_OldNewConsolidated()
   Dim TAncNouv(), L&
   ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path: ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
   TAncNouv = ActiveSheet.Range("folderlist_Cons_pdf[Old-FileName]").Resize(, 2).Value
   For L = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
      Name TAncNouv(L, 1) As TAncNouv(L, 2)
      Next L
   End Sub``` and it is working well ( so I thought that I just needed to add one to integrate my last column)

Comment: I tried to resize to 4 and keeping `Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 3)` to 3 but I have a Error 1004 "Application defined or Error defined error"

Comment: ok I realized it was the end of my table so perhaps there was an issue because there was no more column, so I Resized `TAncNouv = ActiveSheet.Range("folderlist_Cons_pdf[Old-FileName]").Resize(, 3).Value`to 3 and tried with `Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 2)` but still Error 1004

Comment: Oh, it's my fault, in fact, I renamed one of my columns to clarify here for my question StackOverflow ( but it wasn't renamed everywhere) in fact my second solution (putting it in the For loop) work when I'm not an idiot that modify the column filename :(

Answer (score 0):

So in fact moving to the For Loop was the correct way ( just that I made a modification in my table to simplify for the stackoverflow question that was impacting my macro :( ;))

```
Sub Move_Date()
   Dim TAncNouv(), L&
   Dim Fobj As Object
   Set Fobj = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
   ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path: ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
   TAncNouv = ActiveSheet.Range("MovetoFolder[fileName]").Resize(, 3).Value
   
   For L = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
   If Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 3)) = False Then
   MkDir (TAncNouv(L, 3))
   End If
      Name TAncNouv(L, 1) As TAncNouv(L, 2)
      Next L
   End Sub
```